# Keyboard show scroll TextField Up

Tags: scroll, keyboard, uitextfield

in my app I have two TextField, when I go to edit the fields the keyboard covers the textfield, so that the user can not 'fill in the other fields covered by the keyboard ..

According to you what 's the easiest way (I'm a beginner) and functional in order to prevent that the keyboard hides the textfield? All examples are welcome :)

Thanks to all of you Rory

Comment: Think you could do without overfill the view with UIScrollView etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TPKeyboardAvoiding is the easiest and fastest way I've found to solve this common problem. In your storyboard or XIB file, just set your UITableView's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView and you're good to go :)
It works with UIScrollViews too, so it's a good umbrella-solution.

Happy coding!
Z.

Edit: here's the link to the cocoapod: http://cocoapods.org/?q=TPKeyboardAvoiding